# JIRA JQL select issues where issuekey contains key

Tags: key, jira, contains, jql

I can select JIRA issues using this JQL query:

```
issuekey >= PRJ-23
```

results:

```
PRJ-23
PRJ-24
...
PRJ-2345
...
```

How can I select JIRA issues using "contains-like" operator? Smth. like:

```
issuekey contains "PRJ-23"
```

results:

```
PRJ-23
PRJ-230
PRJ-231
...
PRJ-2345
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a substring match on the issue key? (Have you managed to arrange your issue keys such that PRJ-23, PRJ-230, PRJ-231 are actually related? If so, why?)

Comment: I want to create smth like "suggestion box" to select appropriate JIRA issue. User types project code and first digits of the issue key and I want to compose list of the issues that contain this key.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any way to do this with straight JQL, but there are other ways to get what you need:

1) If you want to run this on an external service, you can access the REST API for the Issue Picker.

You can see one example of how it works in Atlassian's [REST API browser](https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-1-0-issues-picker) for jira.atlassian.com.

The `query` field contains the substring match that you want to find (eg. "CONF-301"). The `currentJQL` field also contains the JQL that describes the set of issues in which you want to find substring matches (eg. "project=CONF"). You can also fire up your web browser's debugger, go to view any issue in JIRA, click More->Link, type your substring into the search box, and look in your debugger's Network tab to see what requests it is making to the REST API above. Note that this interface is not documented (ie. it's not a public API and is subject to change without warning in future versions of JIRA).

2) If you are building a JIRA plugin instead, then the [Issue Picker Search Service](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/search/IssuePickerSearchService.html) is listed as a public API, which you should be able to have injected into your plugin. This is the same service that is used by the above REST API.

Comment: Thanks, Scott! REST API browser is a cool tool! :) Unfortunately this operation (api/1.0/issues/picker) gives a strange results :( When I type query=PRJ-11 on my JIRA, I have 2 mattching issues - 115 & 116, but I have more than 250 issues and I should have at least 11 matchng issues (11, 110-119). Probably the reason is that this query is for "History Search" only (as labled in response). Thanks again, I suppose that project key search ordered by date updated desc and issueKey exact equality search together will be enough to select any issue using REST API.

Comment: @AlexGusev, the above API does return more than just the user's issue history. I omitted the requirement of also needing to populate the "currentJQL" field, since with that, it will search beyond the issue history, looking for substring matches within the set of issues you provide. For example, if you set `currentJQL` to "project=CONF" and `query` to "conf-301" then you'll get all issues with substring matches of CONF-301 in the set of issues returned by "project=CONF", in addition to in your issue history. You can always set the JQL to "project=CONF or project != conf" to get all issues.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to retrieve the issue with this exact key and the issues that having their key greater than or equal to the searched key multiplied by 10

something like this
`validateQuery=false&jql=key="KEY"%20or%20key>="KEY0"%20ORDER%20BY%20key`

this way if your key is "PRJ-23"
it will retrieve the issue with key "PRJ-23" and the ones with key larger than or equal "PRJ-230" which will fulfill your requirement of retrieving "PRJ-23, PRJ-230, PRJ-231, etc..."

Comment: While writing raw `jql` in the advanced jql search, I used your query but slightly different: `(issueKey="KEY" OR issueKey>="KEY-12") ORDER by issueKey DESC`